# How to find out what's the hash added to POST method

Tags: python, http, post

I'm writing a python script to periodically check my driving licence status with DVLA. I used the chrome console to find out what form data is being posted and this is how it looks like:

```
url: https://www.viewdrivingrecord.service.gov.uk/driving-record/licence-number

applicantPassportNumber: 
pesel: 6464a709f574de3e7*****ab7e6790aef 
dln: *driving licence number here
nino: *national Insurance here
postcode: *postcode here
dwpPermission: 1
```

I have a problem with the "pesel" field. It changes with each request, however, old ones work when used with python requests POST method. The old ones even work with different licence holder details so it's not generated from form data. I don't want to hardcode it but can't figure out where it's coming from or how it's generated. I'm fairly new and still learning so may be missing something obvious but is there a way to find out what it is?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the page you can see that this is a hidden prepopulated field in the form:

```
<div class="hide">
    <input type="hidden"
    id="pesel"
    name="pesel"
    value="038a858a4***d782b3f"/>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what it's used for. Tracking, rate lmiting, CSRF, who knows.

In any case, your code should first `GET` the form so it can extract the expected value before doing the `POST`. Note that there may be terms of service or technological measures designed to limit the rate at which you can access this page, but if you're doing this "periodically" then it's probably not a problem.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.

I now extracted the value of "pesel" into a string and assigned this string to the dictionary that I'm attaching to the POST but it returns 404? But then if instead of assigning it to the dictionary by variable I'll hardcode the very same string it works.

I'm really confused about this one, it's exactly the same string in dictionary but only works if hardcoded?

Comment: Can't edit the above so a bit more of strange behaviour: I extract the "pesel" from the form and save it to text file, then use it in POST - Fail. I run the POST again with the same "pesel" from file - Success. I really don't understand that behaviour.

Comment: @azkeel.dev: Regarding your first issue, you should look at the actual outgoing `POST` request to see what is different in the two cases. (Since they generated different responses, they must by definition be different in some way.) Not sure about the second issue, but I don't see any reason for storing it in a file. Since you don't know how or why the `pesel` field can change, you need to do a `GET` before `POST` every time to get the current value. No need to save to a file.

Comment: With regards to the file it came out of desperation because I just don't understand the behaviour and tried various things.

Comment: I do GET, grab that hash, stick in POST and it gets me 404. If I save any of the hashes that came so far and feed them in POST I get 200. I even put 3 old hashes in a list, added the new one from GET, and randomly fed back to POST. The current fails each time. I suspect it may have something to do with the applicationPassportNumber, will have to check. Thanks for helping out, appreciate it.

Comment: @azkeel.dev: Look at the actual request being generated, by your working approach, your non-working approach, and when you fill out the form in the browser. There has to be some difference that will be evident there.